# QListWidget in PyQt5 - Moving an item up a list when clicking the up button

Tags: python, pyqt5, repaint, qlistwidget

I have QListWidget in a pyQt5 application. 
The list contains a list of items. 
I select a particular item by clicking the item on the list.
Thereafter, I have a QPushButton **&Up** which is supposed to shift the item up in the list, once on each click, till it becomes the top item in the list.
When I click the button - the pseudo code is as below

```
get the row of the currently selected item
     if it is greater than row 1 then
         delete the item
         re insert the item at - (row - 1)
         set the newly inserted item as the current item
         **This should make the newly inserted item as the current 
           selected item with a blue band indicating selection**
```

**This however does not happen till I don't call the list widget's repaint method.**

`self.__fruit_list` is the  is the QListWidget 
`self.__button_up` is the QPushButton

The slot connection is defined as below:

```
self.__button_up.clicked.connect(self.__up)
```

The slot function is defined as below:

```
@pyqtSlot()
    def __up(self):
        """Move the item up by one row."""
        row = self.__fruit_list.currentRow()
        if row >= 1:
            # Remove the currently selected item.
            item = self.__fruit_list.takeItem(row)
            self.__fruit_list.insertItem(row - 1, item)
            self.__fruit_list.setCurrentItem(item)
            self.__fruit_list.repaint()
```

Why do I have to call the repaint method and why does not the list refresh automatically? 
Is there a way I can do it without repaint() or is there something wrong with my approach? 
Any input will be highly appreciated.

**MRE The minimalistic program listing**

```
"""Demonstrates QListWidget and adding and modifying values using a dialog."""
# Importing the standard python libraries.
import sys

# Importing the PyQt5 libraries.
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QAbstractItemView, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QListWidget, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class FruitListApp(QMainWindow):
    """Fruit List Management Application class."""

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Initialize the Fruit List Application."""
        super().__init__(parent)

        # Setup the widgets.
        self.__fruit_list = QListWidget()
        self.__fruit_list.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)

        self.__button_up = QPushButton("&Up")

        # Layout the widgets.
        button_box = QWidget()
        button_box_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        button_box_layout.addWidget(self.__button_up)

        button_box.setLayout(button_box_layout)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.__fruit_list)
        layout.addWidget(button_box)

        central_widget.setLayout(layout)

        # Setup the main application window.
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        self.setWindowTitle("Edit Fruit List")

        # Setup signals and slots.
        self.__button_up.clicked.connect(self.__up)

    def add_items(self, item_list):
        """Add items provided as a list to the fruit list."""
        # Item is a list.
        if isinstance(item_list, list):
            if len(item_list) > 0:
                # Add items to the list after determining the previous count
                # of items in the list.
                previous_count = self.__fruit_list.count()
                self.__fruit_list.addItems(item_list)
                # Set the first item added from a list as the current
                # selection.
                self.__fruit_list.setCurrentRow(previous_count)
            else:
                QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", "The fruit names list "
                                               "provided is empty.")
                return
        else:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", "The fruit names are not "
                                               "provided as a list.")
            return

    @pyqtSlot()
    def __up(self):
        """Move the item up by one row."""
        row = self.__fruit_list.currentRow()
        if row >= 1:
            # Remove the currently selected item.
            item = self.__fruit_list.takeItem(row)
            self.__fruit_list.insertItem(row - 1, item)
            self.__fruit_list.setCurrentItem(item)
            self.__fruit_list.repaint()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    def main():
        """Main method to test the application."""
        # The fruit list.
        fruit = ["Banana", "Apple", "Elderberry", "Clementine", "Fig", "Guava",
                 "Mango", "Honeydew Melon", "Date", "Watermelon", "Tangerine",
                 "Ugli Fruit", "Juniperberry", "Kiwi", "Lemon", "Nectarine",
                 "Plum", "Raspberry", "Strawberry", "Orange"]

        # Instantiate the application.
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)

        # Instantiate the Fruit List Main Window.
        main_window = FruitListApp()
        # Add the fruit list.
        main_window.add_items(fruit)

        # Display the main application window.
        main_window.show()

        # Start the event loop.
        app.exec_()

    # Start the application.
    main()
```

** Comment out the following line to reproduce problem .** 
`self.__fruit_list.repaint()`

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: I have updated the post. Thank you. :)

Comment: That is not an MRE, I want a code that can make a copy-paste and execute your code and clearly your code is not.

Comment: Copy this code in a .pyw file and run using python3. Thank again.

Comment: Could you show an image of the error, besides which version of PyQt5 and OS do you use?

Comment: The application works totally fine - **till you comment out the said line** in the __up(self) method. Just commenting out the repaint method stops the functionality.I cannot understand why is it. I am on Mac OSX Mojave 10.14.6 and the latest stable version of PyQt5.

Comment: It works for me without calling repaint, PyQt 5.9.2

Comment: I am using PyQt5 5.14.1 .. what OS are you using? Is it the os?? Mine is Mac OSX Mojave 10.14.6 .. Thank you so much for sharing though.